# Multi-language control with combobox

Tags: c++, dll, combobox, visual-studio-2012, multilingual

I'm trying to control language by selecting it in combobox, but I can't even write to the combo any selection as simple text.

Here is sourcecode: [multilang](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23976207/milti.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is that what I'm looking for: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688160.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the language automatically to the systemlanguage, due to creating a folder en-US (or every language tag you want) with a Resources.resw (Don't change it) in it.

To add Items to a ComboBox, open the "Collection" of the Items propperty of your ComboBox, select (at the bottom in the DropDown, next to "Add") "Other type..." and search for "String". Now you can add as many as you want, and edit their text on the right side.

Comment: Can u show me example how do that as u say "with a Resources.resw (Don't change it) in it."  i'm using visual studio 2012 where i can find ""Collection" of the Items propperty of your ComboBox"

Comment: I saw it in a german tutorial ( [link](http://www.visual-world.de/screencast/webcast-folge-1-aufbau-eines-windows-8-projektes-und-lokalisierung/) )

Comment: Verry short translation:
You create a folder with the language tag like en-US ,fr-FR or de-DE
In it you create a Resources.resw ()
In your xaml you give the Objects which which should be chnged a x:Uid tag which you which
then only in the resw 1st column UidTagYouChoose.Text (for lable)
2nd column the text you want to have in it
if you want to know how to put Language spezific text in a ComboBox this should help [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hi-IN/winappswithcsharp/thread/39592e5a-6c7a-425c-be5f-80865f53f539)

Comment: is it on c#? because i'm try do that with c++